# Difference between time () and new MongoDate()?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there a difference between using PHPs `time()` and using `new MongoDate()`?
I need to store created_at and updated_at dates for each documents in by mongoDB collection
so that I can query them by date (for example documents updated last week).

From what I can see time() and new MongoDate() produces the same result?

Comment: Please add the two examples that produce the same result but differ for your case. Otherwise it's not really clear what you wonder about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `time()` is default for the `MongoDate` constructor, from the manual:

```
public MongoDate::__construct ([ int $sec = time() [, int $usec = 0 ]] )
```

You should use `MongoDate` objects to query MongoDB.

If you use the raw output of `time()`, you will store/query for an integer. When you use `MongoDate`, you will be using MongoDB's [Date type](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates) which gives you some additional benefits.

Comment: So I can use time() to save a timestamp to the DB? Why should I use MongoDate when running queries?

Comment: Aha ok. Like MongoId then? But the date look exactly the same in the document? Shouldn´t it be different?

Comment: @Jonathan Clark : it might look the same when `echo`ing because it has a `__toString()` method http://www.php.net/manual/mongodate.tostring.php which returns a string representation of this object.

Comment: Ah ok. I run the query in the terminal and now I can see that it saves as ISOdate when i use new MongoDate(). Will I now be able to query by date intervals?