# Store UTC Date/Time Into MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, date

How do I store a date/time (UTC) into MongoDB using the PHP driver? So in PHP if I do:

```
$utc = gmmktime();
```

Can I simply do:

```
$utc = new MongoDate($utc);
```

Thanks.

Comment: might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275936/difference-between-time-and-new-mongodate

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, this is the solution:

```
new MongoDate(gmmktime());
```

Comment: I think gmmktime() without paramters will give warning in strict mode.